# Could not contact the following nodes: * /joint_state_publisher

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I'm having a problem when I launch RVIZ with a **join_state_publisher**. For exemple, when I do the tutorial from this page ([Building Movable Robot Model with URDF](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Movable%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF)) and I close it.

When I execute roswtf, appears that message:

*"ERROR: Could not contact the following nodes:  * /joint_state_publisher"*

If I try to kill them with *rosnode kill /joint_state_publisher* it seem's that be OK, but if I rerun it I gave the same message.

I think that this is important because in next reruns of RVIZ it doesn't works correctly (the model not appears completly).

Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9351/could-not-contact-the-following-nodes:--*-/joint_state_publisher/) by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally think that I solved the problem.

I forgot to add in my launch file the correct path for the joint_state_publisher and set the gui parameter to true.

Finally, my launch file looks like this:

---

Originally posted by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) with karma: 197 on 2011-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1